# How to make my UITableViewCell not just have a title and a subtitle, but a title, subtitle (date), and another label (summary)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, rss

Trying to make an my RSS Feed app have the summary inside the label, I have parsed the description (summary), but I don't understand how to add it in the UITableViewCell. I am currently using UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle, so I can show the title of each post and the date below it. **How do I add one more below it to show summary of each post?**

**MasterViewController.h (TableView Header)**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class RSSChannel;
@class WebViewController;

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
<NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableData *xmlData;

    RSSChannel *channel;
}
- (void)fetchEntries;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WebViewController *webViewController;

@end
```

**MasterViewController.m (TableView Implementation)**

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "RSSChannel.h"
#import "RSSItem.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"


@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController
@synthesize webViewController;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self fetchEntries];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}


- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"The amount of items in the table: %u", [[channel items] count]);
    return [[channel items] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    }
     RSSItem *item = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[item title]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[item date]];
    return cell;
}


- (void)fetchEntries
{
    // Create a new data container for the stuff that comes back from the service
    xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    // Construct a URL that will ask the service for what you want -
    // Note we can concatenate literal strings together on multiple lines in this way it 
    // results in a single NSString instance
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                  @"http://sephardijews.com/feed/"];

    // Putting the URL we made into an NSURLRequest, so we can connect to the url data that we specifed
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Creating a connecting that will exchange this request for the data from the URL we specifed
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req
                                                 delegate:self 
                                         startImmediately:YES];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
    didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
   qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"%@ found a %@ element", self, elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"channel"]) {

        // If the parser saw a channel, create new instance, store in our ivar
        channel = [[RSSChannel alloc] init];

        // Give the channel object a pointer back to ourselves for later
        [channel setParentParserDelegate:self];

        // Set the parser's delegate to the channel object
        [parser setDelegate:channel];
    }
}

// Method used to start at the beginning of the instance of the tableview, it will intialize the connection method to retrieve the posts from the URL

/* - (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self) {
        [self fetchEntries];
    }

    return self;
}
 */

// This method will be called several times as the data arrives
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Add the incoming chunk of data to the container we are keeping
    // The data always comes in the correct order
    [xmlData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{
    // Create the parser object with the data received from the web service
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];

    // Give it a delegate - don't worry about the warning
    [parser setDelegate:self];

    // Tell it to start parsing - the documet will be parsed and the delegate of NSXMLParser will get all of its delegate messages sent to it before this line finishes execution - it is blocking
    [parser parse];

    // Get rid of the XML data as we no longer need it
    xmlData = nil;

    // Get rid of the connection, no longer need it
    connection = nil;

    // Reload the table
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%@\n %@\n %@\n", channel, [channel title], [channel infoString]);

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Release the connection object, we are done with it cause' there is no connection
    // Setting the connection to nil will stop the connection because it is nothing/0
    connection = nil;

    // Release the xmlData object. We stopped to connection to put the data in the xmlData object, so we set it to nil also
    xmlData = nil;

    // Grab the description of the error object passed to us, so we can tell the user
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fetch failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]];

    // Create and show an alert view to the user with the error string to tell them the error in the process of the connection
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                 message:errorString
                                                delegate:nil 
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [av show];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // Push the web view controller onto the navigation stack - this implicitly
    // creates the web view controller's view the first time through
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

    //Grab the selected item
    RSSItem *entry = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    //Constructs a URL with the link string of the item
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry link]];

    // Construct a request object with that URL
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Load the request into the web view
    [[webViewController webView] loadRequest:req];

    // Set the title of the web view controller's navifation item
    [[webViewController navigationItem] setTitle:[entry title]]; 

}



/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the UITableViewCellStyle to custom and dragging in your own UITextLabel objects to the prototype cell. Make `@property`s for each of your data items in your TableViewController...

```
@interface MasterViewController () 

    NSMutableArray *_objects;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *date;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *summary;

@end
```

Then connect the UITextLabels to their respective data.